# What is 'Suspense' in React, and how does it relate to a Promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Concurrent React expands the concept of Suspense, introduced in React 16.6.

According to [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html):

> Suspense lets your components “wait” for something before they can render.

To what extent is this a different concept to a Promise?

Comment: A `<Suspense>` is a React component, a promise is not. `<Suspense>` offers a declarative way to have a fallback display while a resource is still loading (which could be a promise), but this is not tangible like a promise object but uses some React magic to detect what it is waiting for.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, it's very similar to what a Promise does, except that it's conditional. A really common use case is showing a loading component while the data that the primary component relies on is loaded.

```
import React, { lazy, Suspense } from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Loading from './Loading'

const ItemList = lazy(() => import('./ItemList'))

const App = props => {
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
            <Route path="items" component={ ItemList } />
        </Suspense>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you ask about the Suspense component, you can think about `<Suspense/>` as loading boundary (like error boundary) and you can set loading granularity.

But If you ask about suspense mechanism:

When required data by a component isn't ready, component abort rendering by throwing a promise. When the promise is resolved, react will render the component again. This time data is ready and the component can continue rendering. Note that the component function will be called from the start and this is why you shouldn't have side effect inside the body of render.

Note that in this mechanism there is no async function or wait.

```
                                        // time -->
function SomeComponent(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState()  // 1           3
  const posts = resource.posts.read()   //  2 ops wait ^4  
  useSomeHook()                         //  ^          | 5
  return <div>...</div>;                //  |          |  6
}                                       //  |          |
                                        //  |          ^ data is ready,
                                        //  |            compnent re-render
                                        //  |            again from start
                                        //  |
                                        //  ^ data is missing, throw promise,
                                        //    react will re-render component
                                        //    when promise is resolved
```

Answer (score 1):

Suspense is like a promise but specifically made for rendering and state management.

A promise is language specific or code specific.

Suspense is like a promise for your UI.

Answer (score 1):

In React, "Suspense" is a feature that allows components to suspend rendering while they're waiting for some asynchronous operation to complete, such as data fetching or code-splitting. It helps in improving the user experience by preventing the display of incomplete or empty content while waiting for data to be loaded.

The primary use case for Suspense is to handle asynchronous operations within the component tree. When a component that is wrapped in a Suspense boundary encounters a promise (such as a data fetching request) during rendering, it can pause rendering and show a fallback UI until the promise is resolved.

Here's a basic example of how Suspense can be used for data fetching:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const fetchData = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('Data loaded successfully');
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const DataComponent = React.lazy(() => fetchData());

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>React Suspense Example</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <DataComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In this example, the `DataComponent` is a lazy-loaded component that fetches data asynchronously using the `fetchData` function. The `Suspense` component wraps the `DataComponent` and provides a `fallback` prop, which is the UI to be displayed while waiting for the data to load. When the `DataComponent` is being loaded, the fallback UI is shown, and once the data is fetched, the actual component is rendered.

It's important to note that Suspense is not only limited to data fetching but can also be used with other asynchronous operations like code splitting. Additionally, Suspense works well with React's concurrent mode, which is an experimental set of features designed to help React apps stay responsive and gracefully adjust to the user's device capabilities and network speed.**strong text**